# Python Plotly: display temporary message during long callback

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm using Plotly / Dash to display 5 graphs.  When the user selects the desired part number (from a dropdown list), it takes a few seconds to update the graphs.  Can I first have a callback that changes a text output to "please wait" and then a second callback that updates the actual plots?  I don't want the user clicking the dropdown again or thinking that the server is hung up.

BTW, is there a list somewhere of the different output types (figure, etc.) ?  I can't find any information on how to update a text box with a callback.

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code you used to generate this dash app? it's going to be a bit difficult to make a suggestion otherwise

Comment: This is a pretty generic question.  When the callback executes, it takes some time to due the amount of data being processed.

Comment: that's fine too – it just means that you're going to get generic answers like examples straight from the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into [loading states](https://dash.plotly.com/loading-states). You can display a spinner or text telling the user that a component is loading.

Comment: That works!  Thanks, Derek.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped Mark